# How can I restore my computer to factory default using the command line?

Tags: command-line, configuration, troubleshooting

How can I use the command line to restore my computer to factory settings?

Comment: what do mean factory default? which device? it need to more explanation.

Comment: Do you mean that your computer shipped as Ubuntu factory default ?

Comment: Please add information on brand and how this is related to Ubuntu

Comment: The question is very unclear, but you could just reinstall Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

You can reset the configuration for all packages that use debconf with the command

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh -a`

This will restore a large portion of your system, although there will likely be things that are still configured and set.